# Allow user to define settings in HTML for custom Razor component

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-component

Lets say I have a custom razor component, called MyComponent. This component inherits from ComponentBase, lets assume its a version of data grid control. The code examples I found on internet, use this code as example to configure some behavior:

```
// index.razor
<MyComponent EditSettings=@_editSettings SelectionSettings=@_selectionSettings>
  ...

</MyComponent>

@code {
  EditSettings _editSettings;
  SelectionSettings _selectionSettings;

  // somewhere in some method
  _editSettings = new EditSettings() { ... };
  _selectionSettings = new SelectionSettings() { ... };
}
```

Technically speaking, EditSettings and SelectionSettings exist to define behavior of the component. I would like to add support for developer to configure behavior for this component inside HTML, and not in c# code behind. Take a look at this hypothetical example that I am interested in:

```
// index.razor
<MyComponent>
  <EditSettings AllowEdit="..." EditMode="..." OnEditCompleted="..." />
  <SelectionSettings SelectionMode="..." OnSelectionChange="..."  />
  ...

</MyComponent>
```

As far as I understand, in order to show them inside razor's HTML code, they need to inherit from ComponentBase? Is this correct?

How would I catch inside MyComponent code that user defined them? Their existence is optional, user can choose not to define them and use default behavior.

Comment: Based on the lack of replies (I don't get the "define settings in html"), you may need to add some addition detail to your explanation.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I have modified the question, hope now it is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by cascading the `Settings` objects to the child components by using the [`CascadingValue` component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#cascadingvalue-component). Also add an `event` to the `Settings` classes so that when the child components change the settings the parent component gets notified. Example:

`SettingsA.cs`:

```cs
public class SettingsA
{
    private bool? _allowThis;
    private bool? _allowThat;

    public bool AllowThis
    {
        get => _allowThis ?? false;
        set
        {
            _allowThis = value;
            NotifyStateChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool AllowThat
    {
        get => _allowThat ?? false;
        set
        {
            _allowThat = value;
            NotifyStateChanged();
        }
    }

    public event Action? OnChange;

    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
```

`MyComponentSettingsA.razor`:

```
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private SettingsA? SettingsA { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool AllowThis { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool AllowThat { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (SettingsA != null)
        {
            SettingsA.AllowThis = AllowThis;
            SettingsA.AllowThat = AllowThat;
        }
    }
}
```

`MyComponent.razor`:

```
@implements IDisposable

<CascadingValue Value="_settingsA">
    @if (ChildContent != null)
    {
        @ChildContent
    }
</CascadingValue>

@if (_settingsA.AllowThis)
{
    <p>This is allowed</p>
}

@if (_settingsA.AllowThat)
{
    <p>That is allowed</p>
}

@code {
    private SettingsA _settingsA = new SettingsA();

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _settingsA.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _settingsA.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<MyComponent>
    <MyComponentSettingsA AllowThis="true" AllowThat="true" />
</MyComponent>
```

[BlazorFiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/6ffnfvr6)